# Matrix addition/multiplication in numpy

Tags: python, math, numpy, matrix

Forgive me, it's been nearly 20 years since I've pulled out my matrix math.

I have a point in space:

```
point1 = (x, y)
```

I have a scaler:

```
scaler = 0.5
```

I have a transformational matrix:

```
xform_matrix = [
    ( 1.0,  1.0),
    ( 1.0, -1.0),
    (-1.0, -1.0),
    (-1.0,  1.0)
]
```

I want the final matrix to be:

```
new_matrix = [
    (x + (1.0) * 0.5,  y + (1.0) * 0.5),
    (x + (1.0) * 0.5,  y - (1.0) * 0.5),
    (x - (1.0) * 0.5,  y - (1.0) * 0.5),
    (x - (1.0) * 0.5,  y + (1.0) * 0.5),
]
```

What are the numpy matrix operations to perform the translation above?

Thanks much in advance!

Comment: Are you essentially trying to do a dot product?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think something like the following is what you are looking for:

```
>>> point1 = (3, 5)
>>> scalar = 0.5
>>> xform_matrix = np.array([[1., 1.], [1., -1.], [-1., -1.], [-1., 1.]])
>>> (xform_matrix * scalar) + point1
array([[ 3.5,  5.5],
       [ 3.5,  4.5],
       [ 2.5,  4.5],
       [ 2.5,  5.5]])
```

If you actually meant to apply the scalar after the addition like `(x + 1.0) * 0.5` then you can use the following:

```
>>> (xform_matrix + point1) * scalar
array([[ 2.,  3.],
       [ 2.,  2.],
       [ 1.,  2.],
       [ 1.,  3.]])
```

Comment: Thank you!  I was looking for the first answer you gave.